# Google Apps Script - Access to different account (contact-api) via OAuth2-authentication

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0

Retrieve/Update Google-Contacts from Apps Script (Spreadsheet)

Environment Desc:

We have a shared spreadsheet belonging to a domain-account "PrimContact" where we also manage our contacts. 
The spreadsheet is shared with selected users in the domain with r/w-access. 
Workflow so far: after making changes to the spreadsheet persist those changes through script-call.
This api-call was authorized via clientAuth and as of a few days that won't work anymore.
Through clientAuth we were able to allow all the users to manipulate the sheet and finally update
the contacts of the targeted contact (PrimContact).

Problem:

Reading up about deprecation of clientAuth I tried, and somewhat succeeded, to change
authentication to OAuth2. As I understand things there are two ways I can authenticate a 
user. Through a clientAccount or via serviceAccount.
SideNote: The following two pages helped a lot in getting it done, especially for serviceAcc.

[1]client account with: https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2

[2]service account auth with: https://github.com/mcdanielgilbert/gas-oauth2-gae

For that to work I added a project to PrimContact-user and created both a web-account and a 
service account. Using aforementioned scripts as a starting point authentication works too, but
in the end it's not what I am trying to accomplish.

Client Account: the script is calling the api (contact-api) with an access token for the currently
logged in client although I provided the clientId of the PrimContact-user. Now I COULD run the script as PrimContact-user beforehand and store the token
in the document. If the access-token has not expired yet the other users can work with this
token just fine and therefore "operate" on the PrimContact-data. But as soon as the token
expires I would have to call the script as PrimContact-user again, which is not to very comfortable.

Service Account: got it working with gas-oauth2-gae, but the contact-list is empty. The call
itself is successfull though. I guess this is due to the service account not being tied to
the PrimContact-user although the project is associated with this user?

Goal:

Making an api-call (contacts) inside google-apps-script(spreadsheet) used by different users and 
manipulate contact-data of a different account, i.e. the account who originally shared the spreadsheet.

Maybe I'm getting the whole idea of OAuth2 completely wrong, so far my understanding of the
clientAccount-thing is that the currently logged in user allows the project (which belongs to the 
PrimContact-user) to manipulate the data of the currently logged in user. 
What data the service-account-authenticated call is manipulating.. I'm not quite sure..

If it helps I can add the code-snippets, but as everythings "working" & still not doing what
I really need it to do I'm not sure if it's helpful.

Comment: Have you implemented domain wide delegation on your domain for the service account?  by doing so, the service account can impersonate the users in your domain, in this case it would impersonate the PrimContact-user and then it will be able to perform actions on that user's behalf. check this for more information: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation

Comment: No I have not done that yet. Will try and check if it works, for now it sounds just like it could be what I was looking for.

Comment: Turns out the PrimContact user isn't allowed to alter these settings and we currently have no way to change that (part of a larger organization). Dunno how to proceed from here on out, but thanks for your input anyway! As far as I can see your suggestion should work, looking forward to provide proof.. if company admins enable me to do so, that is ;)